# Store terminal node split rule of ctree into a dataframe in R

Tags: r, decision-tree, party

I have a dataset (Node1) which contains 6 brands and on applying ctree(), the same is split into 2 terminal nodes.
Node2 contains 4 brands
Node3 contains 2 brands.
I would like to extract these brands of each terminal node and store them in two different dataframes. Please suggest how to do the same.

This is what I have coded :

```
    library("party")
    library(gridExtra)
    fileName <- "C\\"
    data <- read.csv(paste(fileName, ".csv", sep=""), header=TRUE)
    pdd <- subset(data, select=c(col1,col2))

    pdd_ctree <- ctree(col1~col2, data=pdd, controls =  ctree_control(minsplit=30))

    print(pdd_ctree@tree$psplit$splitpoint[1:6])
    print(pdd_ctree@tree$psplit$splitpoint)
```

The result that I get is :

```
    print(pdd_ctree@tree$psplit$splitpoint[1:6])
    [1] 1 0 1 1 0 1

    print(pdd_ctree@tree$psplit$splitpoint)
    [1] 1 0 1 1 0 1
    attr(,"levels")
    [1] "Brand01"            "Brand02"                "Brand03"          "Brand04"             
    [5] "Brand05" "Brand06"
```

My requirement :

Have 2 dataframes left.df and right.df

left.df will contain [Brand01,Brand03,Brand04,Brand06]

right.df will contain [Brand02,Brand05]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just want:

```
lvls <- levels(pdd_ctree@tree$psplit$splitpoint)
left.df = lvls[pdd_ctree@tree$psplit$splitpoint == 1]
right.df = lvls[pdd_ctree@tree$psplit$splitpoint == 0]
```